# How to set Cassandra (>2.0) JVM heap size of 8GB?

Tags: java, cassandra, jvm, cassandra-2.0

How to set Cassandra (>2.0) JVM heap size of 8GB?  When I type in `free -m` it gives me the following. How can I set the Cassandra JVM heap size to 8GB?

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         16047      11336       4711          0         81       5814
-/+ buffers/cache:       5441      10606
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in the [Tuning Java resources](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html) section of the documentation:

> If you decide to change the Java heap sizing, both MAX_HEAP_SIZE and HEAP_NEWSIZE should should be set together in conf/cassandra-env.sh.

Inside cassandra-env.sh, search for this line:

```
#MAX_HEAP_SIZE="4G"
```

That line in the code happens after the MAX_HEAP_SIZE calculations have happened, so it works as an override.  Uncomment it, and set it accordingly.

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="8G"
```

Be careful going above 8G.  For guidance on tuning the JVM, I recommend [Amy Tobey's Cassandra 2.1 Tuning Guide](https://tobert.github.io/pages/als-cassandra-21-tuning-guide.html).  She offers some tips for tuning CMS, as well as a great section on implementing the new G1GC.

Comment: what should HEAP_NEWSIZE  be set to? from your response

Comment: The old way was to set 100mb per CPU core, now (for CMS) the usual advice is to start with around 25% of your `MAX_HEAP_SIZE`.

Answer (score 3):

**Update `cassandra-env.sh`**

remove / comment out the entire `calculate_heap_sizes()` function

- this is the function that is called by cassandra to automatically allocate JVM size.
- it takes the lower of 1/4 system memory or 8GB. This is why the default max JVM size is 8GB

Remove/comment out other line with `$MAX_HEAP_SIZE`.

- The line starts with: *"only calcuate the size if..."*
- delete / keep HEAP_NEWSIZE commented out

set `MAX_HEAP_SIZE` to the new value. Ex: `16G`

- this should be the only place you need to do this

**Restart**

- Ideally, you'd only need to restart the Cassandra service. However, I've only gotten it to work after restarting the entire machine.

Also see for another example: https://medium.com/@mlowicki/move-cassandra-2-1-to-g1-garbage-collector-b9fb27365509