# How to restrict Cassandra to fixed memory

Tags: cassandra, thingsboard

We are using cassandra in order to collect the data from thingsboard. The memory it started  with was 4GB (after executing the systemctl status for cassandra) and after 15 hours it has reached up to 9.3GB. 
I want to know why is there this much increase in memory and is there any way to control it or to restrict it to use fixed amount of memory without the data being lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34745419/how-to-set-cassandra-2-0-jvm-heap-size-of-8gb) for setting max heap size used . But tune cassandra gc properly when you change this.